# NetSuite/SuiteScript 2.0 - How to Assign New Customer to Support Case

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

I have an AfterSubmit UserEventScript (support case) that correctly does the following:

1. Loads an associated custom record type
2. Creates a new Customer with Address using that custom record
3. Saves the newCustomer to the database

   ```
           newCustomer.commitLine({
               sublistId: 'addressbook'
           });

           newCustomer.save({
               enableSourcing: true,
               ignoreMandatoryFields: false
           });
   ```

To my question, what are the next steps for replacing the old Customer with this newly created Customer on the support case? I've tried the following code, but it logs an "undefined" value.

```
          recordSubmitted.setValue({
            fieldId: "companyid",
            value: newCustomer.companyId            
          });
```

Comment: @erictgrubaugh Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The internal id of the new customer record is returned from the save function. The field you want to assign to has script id 'company'. So:

```
    var custId = newCustomer.save({
        enableSourcing: true,
        ignoreMandatoryFields: false
    });

   recordSubmitted.setValue({
        fieldId: 'company',
        value: custId            
   });
```

Generally if you are choosing a different customer to assign the case to you should consider whether the different customer already exists so you might have loaded the other customer or found it via a search.

from a load and verify:

```
   recordSubmitted.setValue({
        fieldId: 'company',
        value: differentCustomer.getValue({fieldId:'internalid'})            
   });
```

from a search you might get the id directly:

```
var custId = null;
mySearch.run().each(function(res){
    if(test(res)){
       custId = res.id;
       return false;
    }
    return true;
});

if(custId) recordSubmitted.setValue({
    fieldId: 'company',
    value: custId            
});
```

Comment: Thank  you for your prompt response. The log is now showing the internal ID (custId) of the newly created customer; however, the recordSubmitted.setValue is NOT updating the support case with new company/customer.

Comment: You would have to update the case in the before submit user event OR load the  case record; update it and save it again. (or do that via submitfields)

Comment: Thanks again! Switched to beforeSubmit entry point, and everything is now working perfectly.